# How to extend root with swaping unallocated space (75.01GiB) ,using full or portion of free space?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, root, gparted

[image: Gparted Screenshot]

I cannot solve it, Any help?

(Note: I've read similar posts and questions but still I couldn't find the right solution)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do this job you have to boot your PC with a Live CD/USB with GParted. This is because you must *unmount* partitions that you want change.

So, after you booted up Live CD/USB your PC, open GParted and check if is no *key* icon is showed next to /dev/sdaX labels. If there is a key it is a sign that the corresponding partition is mounted and so is locked from being modified. (As you can see, in your image all partitions are mounted, because all labels have a key next to them).

To unmount a partition, right click on it and select unmount.

Then you have to move toward right in order partition: **sda9**, **sda8**, **sda7**. You can get an idea from this image: [partition moving idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBg2S.jpg).

After that you can extend root partition (**sda6**).

When you are ready you can apply changes. The entire process will take a lot because GParted have to move 3 partitions, but in the end you should obtain what you wish.

I've done the same procedure to move a small partition around my hard disk.